# JSFiddle example - React, cannot get render to update

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have a **JSFiddle** example I am working on, but cannot get it to work 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/richardmarais/kz0mLnge/13/

As you can see, it renders some colour blocks.

**Example**

When I click on one of the items, the `onClick` event is correctly called.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ul>
          <li>{this.state.items.filter(i => i.isSelected).map(i => i.name).join(', ')}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="Colors">
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name} name={item.name} className={`Colors__item Colors__item--${item.color} ` + (item.isSelected ? 'Colors__item--state-selected' : '')} onClick={this.onClick}>
              {item.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Fragment>
           );
  }
```

The item list is correctly updated (i.e. `isSelected: true`).

```
{name: "colour blue", color: "blue", isSelected: true}
```

**Problem**

The DOM is not updated to reflect the `onClick`.

- The style on the selected item should change to
  `Colors__item--state-selected`.
- The selected `item.name` should be
  written to the top of the Fragment.

**Additional Question**

The `onClick` function gets the `item.name` from the event (`e.target.textContent`). Is there a way to rather pass the `item.name` as a parameter on the `onClick` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is not updating, you need to use `setState` like,

```
toggleItemSelectedState (name) {
    console.log(name);
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(i => {
        return name === i.name ?
          { ...i, isSelected: !i.isSelected } :
          i
      })
    })
  }
```

About additional question,

You can directly send `item.name` like,

```
onClick={()=>this.onClick(item.name)}
```

And the function should be,

```
onClick = (name) => {
    this.toggleItemSelectedState(name);
    console.log(this.state.items[0]);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ravibagul91/ft5j2pLh/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are correct. However, the reason I did not use `setState()`, is because then I get the following error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null`. Do you know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong you can directly replace your function with my answer. I have tested this code on your fiddle only.

Comment: Thank you. I was doing setState when initialising, I see it needs to be done on update

Answer (score 2):

Don't assign `state` directly, this is your problem. You have to use method `this.setState()`. More information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

And additional question - you can handle it in two ways

- (easy one but not perfect, this will create anonymous function each render) - just pass to `onClick` function like this: `oClick={(event) => this.onClick(event, item.name)}` and in your `this.onClick` method handle extra `name` parameter or
- (recommended) create new `<Item>` component and and pass all parameters `<Item object={item}>`. Inside this new `Item` component you can just have then `onClick` method and use inside it `this.props.object` param.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are correct. However, the reason I did not use `setState()`, is because then I get the following error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null`. Do you know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Here you have working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3a90qhvd/ You have to also call `super()` with props in `constructor()`.

Comment: Thank you. I was doing setState when initialising, I see it needs to be done on update

Answer (score 0):

@pako is right. You need to use `setState()` to update the state to cause the DOM to re-render.

As to your additional question, you can use `onClick = {()=>this.onClick(item.name)}` to pass it directly to `onClick` call.